# Image with Title at bottom

Tags: iphone

Is there any special control available in UIKit to display a screen like iPhone's app listing  screen, i.e. Image with title at bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any controls available in the base libraries to do what you mention. However it would not be very difficult to simply subclass a UIImageView so that it includes a UILabel located just below the image. This can be done in many ways and is not very hard.

A basic idea would be something like:

Header:

```
@interface ImageTextView : UIImageView  {
    UILabel *title; 
}

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame;
-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)_title; 

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation ImageTextView

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:_frame]){
        self.layer.masksToBounds = NO; 
        title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,_frame.size.height,_frame.size.width,50}];
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
        title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        [self addSubview:title]; 
    }

    return self; 
}

-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)_title{
    title.text = _title; 
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [title release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And then to use it you would use code like:

```
ImageTextView *test = [[ImageTextView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,100,100}];
test.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example.png"];
[test setTitle:@"TEST"];
[mainView addSubview:test];
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: You're right but personally (IMHO) I'd make a xib that contained both an UIImageView and a UILabel instead of putting the label inside the image. It's a bit more effort but you get more flexibility with scaling/sizing the image / seperation between the image and the text etc

Comment: @deanWombourne Yes you could. Personally though I do all of my development programatically so I wouldn't know much about implimenting this using a xib. You could accomplish the same thing however by subclassing a UIView instead of a UIImageView and adding both a UIImageView and a UILabel to it. This would essentially result in the same level of flexibility. The approach I posted though is a little simpler.

Comment: You're absolutely right - your answer is the simplest way - I'm assuming when Vishnu sees it it will get accepted :) You should have a play with interface builder, once you get over the horrible interface oddities you can get faster feedback on how your ui is going to look.

Comment: Thanks for your simplest solution